# Android: play media file after recording it with MediaRecorder

Tags: java, android, audio

Having troubles playing back something I just recorded with the MediaRecord class.

Code:

```
                    try {
                        audioSample = File.createTempFile("sample", ".wav", PlayScreen.this.getCacheDir());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "ERROR: unable to create temp audio file!" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    recorder.setOutputFile(audioSample.getAbsolutePath());
                    try {
                        recorder.prepare();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "RECORDER ERROR: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("PLAYSCREEN", e.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                    recorder.start();
```

That's the recording. I think it's working because I'm not catching any of the errors ;)

Now for the playback code:

```
                   try {
                        mp.setDataSource(audioSample.getAbsolutePath());
                        mp.prepare();
                        mp.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(PlayScreen.this, "PLAYBACK TEST FAIL: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

This exceptionb I do catch: `java.io.IOException: prepare failed`

Any ideas what could be going on here? I'm guessing the `setDataSource` call is incorrect.

EDIT - from the stackTrace:

```
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0xFFFFFFFC
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at com.jsx.audiotech.PlayScreen$1.onClick(PlayScreen.java:125)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2461)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8890)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 12:35:35.609: W/System.err(24730):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-08 12:35:35.613: W/System.err(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 12:35:35.613: W/System.err(24730):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-08 12:35:35.613: W/System.err(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
01-08 12:35:35.613: W/System.err(24730):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-08 12:35:35.617: W/System.err(24730):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post more of the stack trace so that we can see the actual error? Instead of putting it in a toast, use `e.printStackTrace()`, and it should give you more information on exactly went wrong

Comment: Updated the OP with stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest downloading the .wav file that is created (via emulator is easy with DDMS) and make sure you have a valid .wav file.  I assume you called .stop on the MediaRecorder probably in an event.  If not, you might be trying to prepare an audio file that is still open by the MediaRecorder.